Reloading Ajax Data Table after date change
I'm creating a Booking dashboard on my asp.net MVC project. Here I have given the DateTime selector for the main view and from the script, I'm assigning the current date to the date time picker on the document ready function.
then it passes the current date to ajax via the Ajax data table returns the data assigns it to the table and shows the data.
Here I have added the table on the partial view. The reason I added this table to the partial view is to reload the partial view when if there is any change.
Here is my HTML view code
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="date-container">
            <input type="date" id="bookingDate" name="bookingDate" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"> 
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ArrivingSection"); } </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_InProcessJobsSection"); } </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6"> 
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_FutureBookingsSection"); } </div>
  </div>


This is the current working script that get the data from the controller and show on the table.
 $('#arriving').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    filter: true,
    scrollY: '200px', // Set the fixed height for the table
    orderMulti: false,
    ajax: {
       url: '@Url.Action("GetArrivingInformations", "Booking")',
       type: "POST",
       datatype: "json",
    },
    columns: [{
          "data": "CustomerName",
          "name": "Customer Name"
       },
       {
          "data": "ContactNumber",
          "name": "Contact Number"
       },
       {
          "data": "ServiceName",
          "name": "Service"
       },
       {
          "data": "CheckInTime",
          "name": "Check In",
          "render": function (data, type, row) {
             // Assuming data is a TimeSpan object with Hours and Minutes
             if (data) {
                // Convert the TimeSpan to a valid time in Date format
                let hours = data.Hours;
                let minutes = data.Minutes;

                // Create a Date object with the current date but set the time to the TimeSpan's hours and minutes
                let date = new Date();
                date.setHours(hours, minutes);

                // Format the date to AM/PM
                return date.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                   hour: '2-digit',
                   minute: '2-digit',
                   hour12: true
                });
             }
             return 'Invalid Time';
          }
       },
       {
          "data": "EncryID",
          "render": function (data, type, row) {
             // Check if customer has already arrived
             if (row.IsCustomerArrived) {
                // If arrived, don't display the 'Arrived' button
                return `<div class="btn-group bx-pull-right" role="group">
                     <a href="#" class="btn-info btn-sm common-btn" onclick="openAssignJobModal('${data}', '${row.ServiceName}','${row.CustomerName}')">Assign Job</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                 </div>`;
             } else {
                // Display the 'Arrived' button if the customer hasn't arrived
                return `<div class="btn-group bx-pull-right" role="group">
                     <a href="#" class="btn-primary btn-sm common-btn" onclick="markAsArrived('${data}', this)">Arrived</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#" class="btn-info btn-sm common-btn" onclick="openAssignJobModal('${data}', '${row.ServiceName}')">Assign Job</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;

                 </div>`;
             }
          }
       }
    ],
    language: {
       search: "Search"
    }
 });

I want to do the same when date is changed, then pass the date to the controller and get the data and reload the table
This is what I have tried, but it's not working, I got so many errors with the data table scripts. When I added the getting data to the document ready function it get errors like datatable is not defined, Datatable is not loaded like wise errors. Can some one help me to complete this process with this way or any alternative way ?
<script src="~/Addons/DataTable/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


< script >

    var arrivingTable; // Declare this globally so we can access it from the date change function

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Function to safely reload the table
    function safeReloadTable() {
        arrivingTable.ajax.reload();
    }

    // Bind date change event
    $('#bookingDate').on('change', function () {
        console.log('Date changed:', $(this).val());
        safeReloadTable();
    });
    // Set current date in the date picker
    const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    $('#bookingDate').val(today);

    try {
        arrivingTable = $('#arriving').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            filter: true,
            scrollY: '200px',
            orderMulti: false,
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetArrivingInformations", "Booking")',
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "json",
                data: function (d) {
                    return $.extend({}, d, {
                        "bookingDate": $('#bookingDate').val()
                    });
                }
            },
            columns: [
                // Your existing columns configuration
                {
                    "data": "CustomerName",
                    "name": "Customer Name"
                },
                {
                    "data": "ContactNumber",
                    "name": "Contact Number"
                },
                {
                    "data": "ServiceName",
                    "name": "Service"
                },
                {
                    "data": "CheckInTime",
                    "name": "Check In",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (data) {
                            let hours = data.Hours;
                            let minutes = data.Minutes;
                            let date = new Date();
                            date.setHours(hours, minutes);
                            return date.toLocaleTimeString([], {
                                hour: '2-digit',
                                minute: '2-digit',
                                hour12: true
                            });
                        }
                        return 'Invalid Time';
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "EncryID",
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (row.IsCustomerArrived) {
                            return `<div class="btn-group bx-pull-right" role="group">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-info btn-sm common-btn" onclick="openAssignJobModal('${data}', '${row.ServiceName}','${row.CustomerName}')">Assign Job</a>
                            </div>`;
                        } else {
                            return `<div class="btn-group bx-pull-right" role="group">
                                <a href="#" class="btn-primary btn-sm common-btn" onclick="markAsArrived('${data}', this)">Arrived</a>
                                <a href="#" class="btn-info btn-sm common-btn" onclick="openAssignJobModal('${data}', '${row.ServiceName}','${row.CustomerName}')">Assign Job</a>
                            </div>`;
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initializing DataTable:', error);
    }
});

</script>



Please edit your question and add the exact errors that you have, including the error message, stack trace and please describe which line was throwing the errors from the code you have shared.

My intuition tells me that it might because you put the content in partial view. May I know have you tried to put all your codes into the main view instead of creating the partial view? By the way, could you pls share a minimial sample for running your codes in our side? You just plenty of html codes but no backend codes.

The error tells you that DataTable is not defined. This is how you reached out to it:
arrivingTable = $('#arriving').DataTable({
    //...
});

There could be multiple reasons for this problem. You will therefore need to go through this checklist in order to solve the problem:

verify that jquery is in your generated page by studying the structure you have in your Dev Tools. I know you believe it is there, but you will need to double-check
verify that DataTable was included by using your browser Dev Tools
verify that both jquery and DataTable were included exactly once into your page
verify that DataTable's script is after the jquery script in your structure
make sure that your call to .DataTable() happens after both jquery and DataTable libraries were fully loaded, possibly putting it into a document load/ready event (it seems that you already do that, but double-check, please)
make sure arrivingTable exists already in your structure when you call DataTable

For further suggestions you will need to share more details about the errors that you see.

thanks for the solutions. I have tried all these and never worked. and the code is too long and this was the minimum code examples that I could add for this issue to get an idea to others. By the way, I solved this using another method. The issue was encountered because I used Data tables and tried to update and show within that. So I removed data tables and added them as normal tables. Then After the ajax return I simply updated the table again. This worked. Thanks
